# SQL cursor fetch status meaning

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I don't understand the meaning of following lines:

```
   WHILE 1 = 1 
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM SomeCursor INTO @SomeId, @SomeOtherColumn

      IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK
```

What are the meanings of while 1=1? and if fetch status is different than 0?

Comment: [@@FETCH_STATUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187308.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

1=1 is just a short condition which always return true, that is, loop forever (well, until you break out of it elsewhere).

As for fetch status values, as usual MSDN is your friend here. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187308.aspx

> - 0 = The FETCH statement was successful.
> - -1 = The FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set.
> - -2 = The row fetched is missing.

E.g. if you get anything other than 0, things have gone wrong, so there's no point in continuing.

On a side note, MSDN also notes that is is a legacy thing, `@@FETCH_STATUS` is global, and therefore where multiple cursors are being used it is not to be trusted. Instead lookup your cursor's individual fetch status value from the `sys.dm_exec_cursors` dynamic management function.

Answer (score 11):

`WHILE 1=1` is the beginning of a loop and always results in a `TRUE` result, thus making the loop start (and potentially go on forever):

`@@FETCH_STATUS` points if there still are rows to be fetched (or have been fetched) from the cursor.

If there are still rows which can be fetched from the cursor, then `@@FETCH_STATUS` is 0, which shows **SUCCESS**.

If `@@FETCH_STATUS` is **<> 0** (-1 or -2) then it points that there are no more rows that can be returned from the cursor and you have reached its end.

This is the usual condition used to break from a loop that is going over a cursor.

Just as @Lamak commented, here is the [documentation for @@FETCH_STATUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187308.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

This is a trick that is commonly used to avoid writing the `FETCH NEXT` line twice in the code.  It starts an endless loop via `WHILE 1 = 1` and continues until the `@@FETCH_STATUS` returns something other than 0, indicating that it has either reached the end of the cursor, or an error has occurred.

The possible `@@FETCH_STATUS` values are:

```
Return value    Description
0               The FETCH statement was successful.
-1              The FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set.
-2              The row fetched is missing.
```